# sudo pecl install intl and get fatal error: 'ext/standard/php_smart_str.h' file not found

Tags: php

I was trying to install intl, a php extension required by Moodle. I used `sudo pecl install intl` and received the following error:

```
/private/tmp/pear/install/intl/intl_error.h:24:10: fatal error: 'ext/standard/php_smart_str.h' file not found
#include <ext/standard/php_smart_str.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [php_intl.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

When it prompted `Specify where ICU libraries and headers can be found [DEFAULT] :`   I hit enter.

And I have installed autoconf by `brew install autoconf`

How to tackle this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As you can see on [this link](https://pecl.php.net/package/intl) intl is no longer maintained and is not compatible with later versions of PHP. It is now included in **most** PHP distributions. The brew version contains it.

What you should do instead is the following:

- `brew install php@7.3` (or whatever the latest version is)
- `brew link --overwrite --force php@7.3`
- Override the PHP binary in your path see below assuming you are using bash (note that it needs to supersede any other PHP binaries )

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/bin:/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

- Source your bash profile (`. ~/.bash_profile`)
- check the intl module (`php -m | grep intl`)